# How to send Post Data or Form data through java.net.HttpURLConnection to access the webservices

Tags: java, rest

How Could I send the `POST` data to the `REST` web service as `JSON` Object instead of sending as a `String`, as shown in below example:

```html
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class PostCall {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  String url = "https://portal.gamesparks.net/rest/games/295581sUaPkF/mongo/preview/script.PlayerData/find";
  URL obj = new URL(url);
  HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

  // add reuqest header
  con.setRequestMethod("POST");
  con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
  con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic  aWFta2luZy5pbmRpYUBnbWFpbC5jb206a2luZ0AwMDc=");

  // Send post request
  con.setDoOutput(true);
  con.setDoInput(true);
  con.setRequestMethod("POST");

  Query query = new Query("566abd13e4b03618c423050a");
  Par par = new Par(query);
  Gson gson = new Gson();

  OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
  os.write(gson.toJson(par).getBytes());

  // DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
  // wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
  os.flush();
  os.close();

  int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
  System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
  // System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
  System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
  String inputLine;
  StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

  while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
   response.append(inputLine);
  }
  in.close();

  // print result
  System.out.println(response.toString());
 }

}
```

Java code for POST the DATA

```html
public class Par {
  Query query;

 public Par(Query query){
  super();
  this.query = query;
 }
 
}

class Query{
 String _id;
 public Query(String _id){
  super();
  this._id = _id;
 }
}
```

In the above example I am not sure the `POST` data is going to the server or not.

I am adding the pic please see it [image]

Comment: You will always send `String`, but in HTTP header tells how to parse it

Answer (score 0):

You can use google Gson API:
Make a class:

```
class MyClass{

    private String id;

    private String first_name;

    //getter setter
}
```

Then in you code

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.setId("12312312");
myClass.setFirstName("MyName");
Gson gson = new Gson();
os.write(gson.toJson(myClass));
```

Comment: According to your suggestion I edited my code, but still I am Not sure the Post data is appending for body or not because I am querying with _id to that URL the response should return one object instead of that it returning whole Object you can also run that code check it.

Comment: You are sending {"query":{"_id":"566abd13e4b03618c423050a"}} as request Body. Can you tell me the desired request Body as per the Api doc.

Comment: I am not find that particular API doc for that ,with some documentation I formed that URL ,the same URL able to access using POST man but not able to access Java code and I think the requested body is same as you specified

Comment: Using postman you are getting different than using java? Can you tell me the postman request?

Comment: I added the pic regarding how postman is working check it once and see the difference where I am missing

Comment: No both are different, you copy those values and compare it once ,you will get more values in JAVA, in POST MAN you will get only particular id Object data only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98209/discussion-between-joker-and-karthik-pamidimarri).

Answer (score 0):

You can use RestTemplate for the same.

1. Create a class with post objects
2. deploy your project in the server
3. call the URL accordingly

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args){
   RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   JSONInput post = new JSONInput();  
   //create a JSONInput class with all your datas to be posted for URL
   //set the values here for ex: post.setString("test");
   String deployedURl = "http://localhost:portNo/projectName/restService"
   System.out.println(restTemplate.postforObject(deployedURl,post,OutputExpected.class));
   ```

   similarly if it is a get method do the same(if u append values to URL)

   ```
   String getInput = deployedURl+"?input=inputforTest"
   System.out.println(restTemplate.getforObject(getInput ,OutputExpected.class));
   ```

}